# How to setState of a specific slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the value of a particular slider during onChange event. However, this is resulting in setting the values on all the sliders. I was wondering how to set the state of a particular slider during the onChange event.

This is what I've tried so far ([**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vy90rnqvm5))

```
class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 50
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Typography id="label">Slider label</Typography>
        <Slider
          id="slider1"
          value={value}
          aria-labelledby="label"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Slider
          id="slider2"
          value={value}
          aria-labelledby="label"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never used reactjs before, but could it be that your declaring value for both of the sliders? So when one changes your actually updating the value of "value" which is effecting both sliders.

Comment: Can you have a dynamic amount of sliders, or are you wondering how you can handle just these two particular sliders separately?

Comment: @Tholle They're dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an array in state where every element is the value of a slider, and then pass the index with the value to the `onChange` handler to update the correct value.

**Example**

```
class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sliders: [50, 50]
  };

  handleChange = (index, value) => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const sliders = [...previousState.sliders];
      sliders[index] = value;
      return { sliders };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Typography id="label">Slider label</Typography>
        {this.state.sliders.map((slider, index) => (
          <Slider
            key={index}
            value={slider}
            aria-labelledby="label"
            onChange={(event, value) => this.handleChange(index, value)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two sliders defined inside the same class, which makes them share all atributes such as the state variables. If you move one slider, the other will follow because they share that attribute.

To solve this, create a generic slide class and call it twice, outside that class. Each will have its own properties, therefore its own onChange events.

```
class GenericSlider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: 50
    };

    handleChange = (event, value) => {
        this.setState({ value });
    };    

    render() {
        <Slider
            id={this.props.id}
            value={value}
            aria-labelledby="label"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
    }
}

class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Typography id="label">Slider label</Typography>

        <GenericSlider id="slider1"/>
        <GenericSlider id="slider2"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is that possible? When there is an onChange event, then we set the state to the changed value. The component re-renders with new value and all the child components will receive the same value through props. `<Slider value={this.state.value} />` and in the `slider component` it will `value=this.props.value`.

Comment: If you have a class to handle your sliders, you simply have to instantiate one per component. That way, each component will have its own set of properties and events, so you don't have to worry with refferences and stuff.